# Spring Integration - Dynamic Configuration for Pool Size, Queue Capacity for Task Executors and Queues

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In my Spring-Integration Config, I have Queues, Task Executors. I would like to change the Queue Capacity, Task executors Pool Size and fixed-delay. I would like to have a UI Page and should be able to change the config if there are more messages to be processed or if there is heavy load with out have to rebuild and deploy the application.

Ex:

```
<si:service-activator input-channel="MessageChannel" ref="messageHandler" 
                          method="handleMessage" output-channel="ackChannel">

    <si:poller task-executor="messageTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="messageTaskExecutor" pool-size="10"
queue-capacity="10" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

I would like to change this numbers  dynamically and reload the config to pick up the changes. It would be great if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject your Task Executors, Queues and so on as regular beans. And then just set parameters to them at runtime. For example

```
<task:executor id="messageTaskExecutor" pool-size="10"
     queue-capacity="10" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

will produce bean of type `ThreadPoolExecutor` with name `messageTaskExecutor`. So, it may be inject as:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("messageTaskExecutor") // or @Inject @Named("messageTaskExecutor")
ThreadPoolExecutor messageTaskExecutor;
```

After you may just call [messageTaskExecutor.setMaximumPoolSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize%28int%29)

Comment: good, I am having multiple Task executors for multiple service-activators which refers to the same @bean.method() but with different pool-size and queue-capacity for different input & output channels.

Comment: But whay is the problem? Inject every of them using different qualifiers. Or just inject all of them into List<ThreadPoolExecutor>...

Comment: Is there no way of having the xml config work. I am having around 15 to 20 channels, Service-activators and task-executors. If there is no other way then I will rewrite the config in annotation. I read about Message-bus but couldn't find a good example does it help any idea?

Comment: Didn't read your comment earlier. I will implement as annotation then.